# understand and coding of the zero-lag cross-correlation matlab

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation

First of all, I am sorry if I am a dummy and cant understand this part of an article. I have a set of data with 200 channels in which every specific two channels are co-dependent. In the paper it is mentioned:

"
For each channel, we filtered both signals
between 0.5 and 2.5 Hz to preserve only the cardiac component and
normalized the resulting signals to balance any difference between
their amplitude.
"

Question1: this means I need to normalize both co-dependent channels to the average of the median? or just normalize each signal to its own median?

Here is the rest of the paragraph
" 
Then, we computed the cross-correlation
extracted the value at a time lag of 0 to quantify the similarity
between the filtered signals. In-phase and counter-phase identical
waveforms yielded a zero-lag cross-correlation value of 1 and -1
respectively, whereas a null value derived from totally uncorrelated
signals. "

I wrote the code below: but I get -1 or plus one everywhere even for signals that are not codependent it gives me 1 or -1. I guess I am wrong in part of the code but rationally I don't know where. Here is the code

```
datafile='data_sess_03.nirs'
 ch_num=1
  [w,src,det,mlOrg,mlo,mlm,Data,datap,acc1,acc2]=readData(datafile);


   fc=[0.5 2.5];
   dataf=filterData(Data,fc);


  [c,lags]=xcorr(dataf(1,:),dataf(5,:),0); % channel 1 and 5 are 
  codependent

  %% c is -1 and plus one every when even in the noisy channels

   plot(acor,'black')
   [~,I] = max(abs(acor));
   lagDiff = lag(I)/fs
```

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks a lot to help me

Comment: If you want to measure correlation, use `corr`.

Comment: For your question 1, _"normalize"_ in this context normally means that all sample values where divided by their maximum value, as such that now all samples range between -1 and +1. The "rest of the paragraph" is just telling you that results they got for in-phase, counter-phase and uncorrelated signal were exacyly what one would expect as result.